# Replace diferent markdown url images with bash

Tags: bash, sed, markdown

This question is different from others I've seen in stackoverflow since it has to look for a string inside special characters like] or), and replace in different text strings urls associated with a markdown text.
In the other solutions I have found there is only text substitution, I can not find and replace in a loop with different text.

1. I have these images in a text of markdown:

   `...
   ![Image 1](https://i.imgur.com/BHoO2Wr.png "Alt Text 1")
   ...
   ![Image 2](https://i.imgur.com/qNxviLS.png "Alt Text 2")
   ...`

   And new images from imgur from this variables:

   `NEW_IMG1="https://i.imgur.com/xY0DgmM.png"
   NEW_IMG2="https://i.imgur.com/E98NLTT.png"`

How do I change the old images for the new ones in bash?

Change this: BHoO2Wr for xY0DgmM

2. Second question:

If my images are like this:

`...
![any text](https://i.imgur.com/BHoO2Wr.png "other text")
...
![another text](https://i.imgur.com/qNxviLS.png "another thing")
...`

How do I change BHoO2Wr for xY0DgmM and qNxviLS for E98NLTT in bash?

Comment: This question is different from others I've seen in stackoverflow since it has to look for a string inside special characters like] or), and replace in different text strings urls associated with a markdown text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ NEW_IMG1="https://i.imgur.com/xY0DgmM.png"
$ NEW_IMG2="https://i.imgur.com/E98NLTT.png"

$ awk -v new="$NEW_IMG1 $NEW_IMG2" '
    BEGIN { split(new,images) }
    match($0,/^(!\[Image *([0-9]+)]\()[^ ]*(.*)/,a) {
        $0=a[1] images[a[2]] a[3]
    }
1' file
...
![Image 1](https://i.imgur.com/xY0DgmM.png "Alt Text 1")
...
![Image 2](https://i.imgur.com/E98NLTT.png "Alt Text 2")
...
```

if your images are actually just to be replaced in the order they appear rather than by the number in the input file (`[Image 1]`, etc.) then it'd be:

```
match($0,/^(!\[Image[^]]+]\()[^ ]*(.*)/,a) {
    $0=a[1] images[++cnt] a[2]
}
```

and to match any text inside the square brackets:

```
match($0,/^(!\[[^]]+]\()[^ ]*(.*)/,a) {
    $0=a[1] images[++cnt] a[2]
}
```

Comment: If the images are: `![another text](https://i.imgur.com/qNxviLS.png "another thing") and ![any text](https://i.imgur.com/BHoO2Wr.png "other text")`, how can i solve it?

Comment: I updated my answer. See the final script segment.

Answer (score 1):

Now this looks like a job for sed :)

```
# The file containing your markup
FILE="myMarkdown.txt"
# A list of new URLs, first = [Image 1], second = [Image 2]...
IMG=("https://i.imgur.com/xY0DgmM.png" "https://i.imgur.com/E98NLTT.png")
COUNT=1

for i in "${IMG[@]}"; do
        sed -i "s#\[Image $COUNT\](https://i.imgur.com/\(.*\) \(\"Alt Text.*\")\)#\[Image $COUNT\]($i \2#" "$FILE"
        COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
done
```

Just save this as script, change the two first variables, and run it in your favorite bash interpreter :)

Comment: And if each image has a different name. For example, instead of [Image 1], for [Image portfolio], how do I do it?

Comment: Sed without g does only one replace so if you remove the \[Image $COUNT\] blocks from the sed command, it will do one image, reload next URL and do next image with that.

Comment: If the images are: `![another text](https://i.imgur.com/qNxviLS.png "another thing") and ![any text](https://i.imgur.com/BHoO2Wr.png "other text")`, how can i solve it?

Comment: Well... Remove the part you don't need...Replace the sed line with ```sed -i "s#\](https://i.imgur.com/\(.*\) \(\"Alt Text.*\")\)#\]($i \2#" "$FILE"```